# RGB Colours in Office 2011 for MAC

Tags: mac, microsoft-office, colors, rgb

How do I check what are the RGB colours (numbers) for a particular shade in Office 2011 For MAC? Im working on a document in Word in Office for MAC, but when I open the document in MS Word on a PC, the colour appears totally different. If I can find the RGB numbers, I could try to create the same on the PC.

Answer (score 0):

Take a screenshot and paste it into an image program you have installed. If the image program doesn't have a color picker, load the image into [this site](http://imagecolorpicker.com/).